# How to catch the feature activate time

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, feature-activation, feature-receiver

I am trying to write one program such that, when ever a feature is activated then it should display the activated time in the sharepoint list. for that i written following code.

```
public class Feature1EventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
    {
        // Uncomment the method below to handle the event raised after a feature has been activated.

        public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;

            SPList list = web.Lists["Features Tracker"];
            if (list == null)
            {
                Guid listid = web.Lists.Add("Features Tracker", "Trakcs the feature activation time", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
                web.Lists[listid].Fields.Add("Activated Time", SPFieldType.DateTime, true);
                SPView myview = web.Lists[listid].DefaultView;
                myview.ViewFields.Add("Activated Time");
                myview.Update();
            }
                SPListItem listitem = list.Items.Add();
                listitem["Activated Time"] = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

        }
}
```

I created another feature with same functionality. Now there is no error. But, time stamp is not inserted into the "Features Tracker" list. Any solution??

Comment: This code appears to compile fine, and you've not given any error.

Comment: Code is fine. But while deploying it is giving error

Comment: It's impossible to read the text in that image, can you copy the error text?

Comment: @TZHX Error message added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `Update()` method on the SPListItem object.

Also, you want the line:

```
listitem["Activated Time"] = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

to be simply:

```
listitem["Activated Time"] = DateTime.Now;
```

otherwise you'll get an unhandled exception.

This is the code I have, which works (the method being the same one you've selected):

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
SPList list;
try
{

    list = web.Lists["Features Tracker"];
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    list = null;
}
if (list == null)
{
    Guid listid = web.Lists.Add("Features Tracker", "Trakcs the feature activation time", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
    web.Lists[listid].Fields.Add("Activated Time", SPFieldType.DateTime, true);
    SPView myview = web.Lists[listid].DefaultView;
    myview.ViewFields.Add("Activated Time");
    myview.Update();
    list = web.Lists["Features Tracker"];
}
SPListItem listitem = list.Items.Add();
listitem["Activated Time"] = DateTime.Now;
listitem.Update();
```

Comment: Yeah I updated but not working. Even I removed that `if` condition... even it is not working

Comment: @Mihir I've updated my answer with more details, hopefully this is helpful to you.

Comment: @TZHX... I too just done this and my program runs successfully. Thanks for your patience... :)

Answer (score 1):

But at the end of all operations do you do?

```
listitem.Update();
```